# Brans-Dicke theory: could a negative value for $\Omega_{BD}$ mimic a current acceleration of expansion like in LCDM model

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, pressure, astrophysics, cosmological-constant

I am working on Brans-Dicke models, in the simplest form (without cosmological constant) and the other form (with cosmological constant)

I am trying in both cases to estimate by MCMC the different cosmological parameters ($\Omega_m$, $\Omega_k$, $h$, $\Omega_{BD}$, $\omega_{BD}$, $\Psi_0=G\phi_0$ and $F=\dot{\phi_0}/\phi_0$.

(and $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ in BD with cosmological constant).

Up to now, I have only considered positive value for $\omega_{BD}$ (with a prior on $\omega_{BD}$) and I find the general relativity result (especially wiht a power law for scale factor curve).

This is mainly due to the fact that I would like to respect the Cassini-Huygens that gives $\omega_{BD}>4e4$.

To simplify notation and calculation, we define a non-dimensional field $\psi=G \phi$, with $G$ being a present-day gravitational constant. With this notation we define $\psi(t=0)=\psi_0$, which is exactly proportionality factor, meant to be close to unity. Further, let's define $F=\dot{\phi} / \phi=\dot{\psi} / \psi$. Also, for BD theory, critical density can be defined as : $\rho_{\text {crit }}=\frac{3 H_0^2 \phi_0}{8 \pi}=\frac{3 H_0^2 \psi_0}{8 \pi G}$ and $\Omega_r=\rho_r(0) / \rho_{\text {crit }}$, $\Omega_m=\rho_m(0) / \rho_{\text {crit }}, \Omega_k=-\frac{c^2 k}{H_0^2}$. Now we write:
$$
\begin{aligned}
H^2 & =\frac{8 \pi G}{3} \frac{1}{\psi} \rho+\frac{\omega}{6} F^2-H F-\frac{c^2 k}{a^2} \\
& =H_0^2 \cdot \frac{\psi_0}{\psi}\left(\Omega_r a^{-4}+\Omega_m a^{-3}\right)+H_0^2 \Omega_k a^{-2}+\frac{\omega}{6} F^2-H F \\
\dot{F}+F^2+3 H F & =\frac{8 \pi G}{3+2 \omega} \frac{1}{\psi} \sum_i \rho_i\left(1-3 w_i\right)=\frac{3}{3+2 \omega} \frac{\psi_0}{\psi} H_0^2 \Omega_m a^{-3}
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last equation we used the following identity:
$$
\dot{F} \equiv \frac{d}{d t}\left(\frac{\dot{\phi}}{\phi}\right)=\frac{\ddot{\phi}}{\phi}-\frac{\dot{\phi}^2}{\phi^2}=\frac{\ddot{\phi}}{\phi}-F^2,
$$
or in other words, $\ddot{\phi} / \phi=\dot{F}+F^2$.
Putting $t=0$ into first equation and defining $\Omega_{B D}=\frac{\omega}{6} \frac{F_0^2}{H_0^2}-\frac{F_0}{H_0}$, we are getting:
$$
\Omega_r+\Omega_m+\Omega_k+\Omega_{B D}=1,
$$
where $F_0=\dot{\phi}_0 / \phi_0$ and we kept the same definitions of $\Omega_i$ as before. Therefore, in this case the free parameters of the model can be taken as: $\Omega_r, \Omega_k, \omega, H_0$ and $F_0$, and $\psi_0$, with $\Omega_m$ being set by above equation.

So, Finally, I wonder if we could mimic the cosmological constant and the current acceleration with negative values for $\Omega_{BD}$ or by playing or another parameter in Brans-Dicke.

But in this case, even if scale factor is similar to $\Lambda$CDM, this would be surely difficult to respect the solar system constrain $\omega_{BD}> 4e4$ :

Is there a variant of Brans-Dicke or another theory of gravity that could avoid this difficulty to be consisstent between a negative $\Omega_{BD}$ value to estimate and mimic the cosmological constant ?

Comment: Won't that lead to a ghost instability?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.